# Definable Countdowntimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am trying to build a user definable countdown timer, I am using the standard CountDownTimer code and have changed the milliseconds to 9000000 / 1000 to give a 2.5 hour count down, also included the .start(); after the onFinish to get the timer to automatically restart...thats all good...

Question is what is the coding required to allow a user to enter in a HH:MM:SS within the 2.5 hour window and then have the counter count down to 00:00:00 then reset back to 02:30:00 automatically?

This is the only piece if the puzzle I am struggling with..I am currently at work and can't submit my coding but some pointers would be really helpful.

Regards

Dj

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a pointer to the [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) widget ?

Comment: I was looking at using the Countdown timer I haven't looked at timepicker...off the cuff what is?